# zsh conditional OR fails

Tags: zsh

```
# delete git branch
git--() {

  BRANCH=$1

  if [ -n $BRANCH]; then
    BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
  fi

  if [ "$BRANCH" = 'master' || "$BRANCH" = 'develop' ]; then

    red "You should not delete $BRANCH"
    return 0
  fi
}
```

fails with

```
git--:[:8: ']' expected
zsh: master: command not found...
git--:8: command not found: master
No branch specified therefore I'm using the current one: master
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Do you really want to delete the branch master (y/n)?
```

however if I change

**if [ "$BRANCH" = 'master' || "$BRANCH" = 'develop' ]; then**

to

**if [ "$BRANCH" = 'master' ]; then**

eveything works. How can I do OR comparison?

thanks!

Comment: try `-o` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two primary options (of course there are also some less straight forward ones)

1. Use `zsh` syntax and use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`.

   ```
   if [[ "$BRANCH" = 'master' || "$BRANCH" = 'develop' ]]; then
   ```
2. Use `-o` instead of `||` in order to stay POSIX compliant

   ```
   if [ "$BRANCH" = 'master' -o "$BRANCH" = 'develop' ]; then
   ```

If the code is only ever to be run with `zsh`, I would recommend to go with 1.

---

The reason for the error message is that `[` is only a regular command and not part of the `zsh` syntax. `[` expects `]` as last parameter, but `||` is part of the `zsh` syntax and has priority. It acts as a separator between commands and splits the "condition" into two commands

```
[ "$BRANCH = 'master'
```

and

```
"$BRANCH" = 'develop' ]
```

The second command is run, if the first one fails.

Running the first command fails, as the the closing `]` is missing. This leads to the error message:

```
git--:[:8: ']' expected
```

For the second command `"$BRANCH"` is substituted by the value `master`. As there is no command named `master` this returns the error message

```
zsh: master: command not found...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should run your shell script in debug mode, eg 'zsh -x', it'll spit out what variables are at each step so you have a good understanding of what's happening.

The BRANCH variable is being clobbered here;  The -n checks to see if BRANCH has a value and if so updates it.  I expect you meant to use the -z switch;

```
  if [ -n $BRANCH]; then
    BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
  fi
```

I think your script should look more like

```
git--() {
  BRANCH=$1

  if [ -z "$BRANCH" ] ; then
    BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
  fi
  if [ -z "$BRANCH" ] ; then
    if [ "$BRANCH" = 'master' ] || [ "$BRANCH" = 'develop' ] ; then
      red "You should not delete $BRANCH"
      return 0
    else
      git branch $BRANCH -D  || ( red "Could not delete $BRANCH" && return 1 )
    fi
  else
    red "branch not understood"
    return 1
  fi
}
```